# linux + find mechanism with Irregular Expression (find command) or perl

Tags: linux

hi dear friends and good morning

The following question may be complicated and critical for my systems

I have 4 Linux machines with cluster

My target is to find all kind of IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) in every file in the linux system

remark: need to scan each file in the linux system and verify if the file include IP address if yes need to print the IP

as the following

more /etc/inet/file.example1

```
 182.23.2.4
 255.255.0.0
 10.10.1.1
 19.2.*.*
 127.0.0.1
```

more /etc/dir/file1.example2

```
 1.1.1.1 TCP
```

Etc.................

Can I get some creative suggestion that search all IP address and print them

lidia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print the full line that contains something that resembles an IP address. It doesn't check to see if its octets are in the range 0-255.

```
grep -Er '\<([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\>' /*
```

to only print the address without the rest of the line add the `-o` option. To disable printing the filename add the `-h` option.

You could replace the `\<` and `\>` delimiters with `[[:space:]]`.

**Edit:**

Here's one that may be suitable for cases that include asterisks:

```
grep -Er '[[:space:]]((\*|[0-9]{1,3})\.){3}(\*|[0-9]{1,3})[[:space:]]' /*
```

Comment: little problem if the IP is  for example 3.3.*.* can your syntax support this?

Comment: @lidia: see my edit